# insert month codeigniter and jquery (beginner learner)

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Problem when insert month..on segment show 01,02,03 but when i insert to database i show 1,2,3,4

how to set to 01,02,03

view code

```
    $.post("<?php echo base_url('account/save'); ?>",
                {   
                new_sum:$("#test<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").val(),
                status:$("#status<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").val(),
                sum:$("#sum<?php echo $row['br_loc'];?>").html(),
                year:<?php echo $this->uri->segment(4)?>,
                month:<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3)?>

                }, 
                function(data) {
                });                             
                });
```

controller

```
public function save()
{
  $data = array('date_send'=>date("Y-m-d"),
                'ac_month'=>$this->input->post('month'),
                'usr_approve'=>$this->session->userdata('username'),
                'status'=>$this->input->post('status'),
                'new_sum'=>$this->input->post('new_sum'),
                'ac_year'=>$this->input->post('year'));       
 $this->db->insert('account',$data);
}
```

Comment: try to use typecast `'ac_month'=> (string) $this->input->post('month'),`

Comment: also ensure that your `ac_month` is string (i.e., `varchar`, `char` ...) not number

Comment: also cannot. ac_month type character(postgres)

Answer (score 0):

If your `ac_month` column is type INT you cannot keep the leading zeros.

I would go with string `VARCHAR` type or store the month as integer then when retrieving data either inject the leading zeros or simply use [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html%23function_lpad) in your SQL query.

```
SELECT LPAD(ac_month,4,0) as month FROM table
```

Comment: i using postgresql and datatype is character(2). anyway thank you